# Ionic Directive elements not invoking functions (binding) on changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I started my project using the Ionic Side Menu Starter.
I'm trying to get a Rating directive/control to work, from here:
https://github.com/fraserxu/ionic-rating

The module is loaded, and the template objects (the stars) render OK. Binding -from- my model/scope works one-time. But, clicking on the stars does nothing.

Some of the js does get invoked: ng-mouseleave="reset()" is hooked up to the parent element  and does get invoked. But ng-click="rate($index + 1)" is attached to the

that contains the star, and does not (I set breakpoints).

I suspect it may have something to do with the child scopes that are created based on the starter, but don't know.

```
<rating ng-model="review.rating" max="5"></rating>
```

And my controller:

```
angular.module('myapp.controllers').controller('NewReviewCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
    $scope.review = {};
    $scope.review.rating = 3;
});
```

The module is loaded in a separate file:

```
angular.module('myapp.controllers', ['ionic.rating']).controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout) {
...
```

Comment: ionic is very jelous on  focus and mouse events make sure you are not using the star inside an anchor tag,labels or other element that might be grabbing the click handler, some list items directives have the same effect if you are going to use it inside a list don't use the list-item directive use the css classes instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dayan's comment nailed it. I had the rating directive inside a label:

  My Label

It works fine after removing it from inside the label.